# Can I get the text at the time when user is selecting it in EditText from written text in Android?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to know that can I get the selected text by user at time when user is Selecting it from EditText.Is it possible to do it Please Help Me...

Answer (score 2):

Create this file called SelectionListener.java package

```
robbin.android.NeedToWrite_Trial;
public interface SelectionListener
{
    public abstract void onSelectionChanged(myEditText et, int selStart, int selEnd);
}
```

Then in your main function, implement SelectionListener, then declare your variable

```
myEditText et;
```

And in your class myEditText, include this function:

```
@Override
public void onSelectionChanged (int selStart, int selEnd)
{
    super.onSelectionChanged (selStart, selEnd);
    if(selectionListener != null)
    {
        selectionListener.onSelectionChanged(this, selStart, selEnd);
    }
}
```

You then include this function in your main function:

```
public void onSelectionChanged (ScrollWrappedEditText et, int selStart, int selEnd)
{
    selectedtext=(""+getText()).substring(getSelectionStart(), getSelectionEnd());
}
```